# No Address on Member Badge

Tags: civimember

I am trying to print a member badge ID but the address is not showing.  I have it in the system but not displaying on the badge.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Exchange!

By default, the postal address doesn't appear on the badges.  You need to go to **Administer menu » CiviEvent » Event Name Badge Layouts** to customize what's displayed.